# dnn (DotNetNuke): How to set the number of unsuccessful login attempts before the user is locked?

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

In DNN, I would like to change the number of log in attempts before the user is locked.

Answer (score 5):

You can change it in your web.config file under system.web > membership > providers > maxInvalidPasswordAttempts.

Comment: It works !!, I add it inside the  <add ...   (< system.web> <membership> <providers> <add ... maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1" ...>